# FindElement - nested span class in div class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to identify "X" (cancel) button. HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="ingredients-container-header">
<div class="ingredients-container-header-name">Ingredients:</div>
<div class="ingredients-container-header-close">
<span class="material-icons cancel-icon " style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 24px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;">cancel</span></div></div>
```

Tried doing it directly by span but it does not work (the problem might be that, it's not unique (many cancel button has the same span)

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class ='material-icons cancel-icon')]"));
```

The thing which needs to be done, is to go by the class: "ingredients-container-header-close" and then somehow "go down" to the span. Can someone tell me how it can be done? (1 parent element and than few child elements, choosing that child one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this **Xpath** :

```
//div[text()='Ingredients:']/following-sibling::div/span[contains(@class,'cancel-icon')]
```

**cssSelector** would be :

```
div[class^='ingredients-container']+div>span
```

try out one of these !

Comment: Did you try out this cssSelector or Xpath ?

Comment: @cruisespandey - thank you, xpath works correctly:
First of all we're going for the header div (looking for the text inside) then we're using /"following-siblings::div/span[contains(@class, ....) - I don't get that one, siblings are elements on the same level? Also what "::" means? Thank you.

Comment: following-siblings means siblings that are just after the current node

Comment: Yes siblings are elements at the same level but here we have preceding-sibling and following-sibling in Xpath.

Comment: Refer this link for Xpath and clarity about ::  :  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 2):

Your experession must be `//div[@class='ingredients-container-header-close']/span[@class='material-icons cancel-icon ']`. You have extra space in class name.

Comment: Does not work like this, tried both with/ without extra space

Comment: @lxi11 I correct my xpath, but other people gained answer which more correct

Comment: Yes this Xpath is also valid. +1

Comment: Also works correctly! Your're awesome guys! Thanks! :)